# Play2.5 - alternative to play.api.libs.Crypto.generateToken

Tags: scala, token, access-token, playframework-2.5

For generating token, I have been relying on `play.api.libs.Crypto.generateToken` successfully. However it is now deprecated and the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CryptoMigration25) is not very clear to me.

Could anybody tell me:

- which library I should include, preferable as sbt dependency
- the actual function to call

Comment: What is this token used for? should it be generated based on a payload and password? or you just need a way to generate a unique string?

Comment: used for token based authentication (OAuth)

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
val token = (Random.alphanumeric take 40).mkString
```